# The sigma algebra over a "trivial" product

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Consider a sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}=\sigma(\Sigma)$, so that $\Sigma$ is the generating set. Let $X$ be any other fixed set. I am trying to prove that

$\sigma(\{A \times X \mid A \in \Sigma\})=\mathcal{F}\times X$,

where $\mathcal{F} \times X=\{Z \times X \mid Z \in \mathcal{F} \}$.

Notice that the left hand side is not a product sigma algebra, it's simply the sigma algebra generated by sets of the form $A \times X$, where $X$ is the same each time.

Proving that the left hand side is a subset of the right hand is easy, but for the life of me I can't get the reverse inclusion. It seems like you should just be able to "factor out" $X$ in order to make this trivial, but I'm not sure if it's that easy. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the collection of all sets $A \in \mathcal F$ such that $A \times X$ belongs to $\sigma(\{A \times X \mid A \in \Sigma\})$. This contains $\Sigma$ . Verify that it is a $\sigma-$ algebra. It follows that this collection contains $\mathcal F$ which is what you want to prove.

[$A^{c}\times X =(X\times X) \setminus (A \times X)$].

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works!